# Open XML File into data grid view algorithm, datatable doesn't support schema inference from xml

Tags: c#, xml, datagridview, save

so I have found the below code for save to take what is in a datagridview and save it to an xml file. I am trying to write the function that does the opposite (open). So far I have the below code and it works until the rows section. I can't quite figure out the logic at the bottom to do what I need it to do. So far all I'm getting are errors about types not matching. Any help would be appreciated. Also I'm getting an odd error in the open function about DataTable does not support schema inference from Xml. When I try to readxml?

```
private void saveToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable("itemstable");

            for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.ColumnCount; i++)
            {
                dt.Columns.Add(dataGridView1.Columns[i].Name, typeof(System.String));
            }

            DataRow myrow;
            int icols = dataGridView1.Columns.Count;
            foreach (DataGridViewRow drow in this.dataGridView1.Rows)
            {
                myrow = dt.NewRow();
                for (int i = 0; i <= icols - 1; i++)
                {

                    myrow[i] = drow.Cells[i].Value;
                }
                dt.Rows.Add(myrow);
            }

            dt.WriteXml("items.xml");
        }

        private void openToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable("itemstable");

            dt.ReadXml("items.xml");

            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
            {
                dataGridView1.Columns.Add(dt.Columns[i].ColumnName.ToString(), dt.Columns[i].ColumnName.ToString());
            }

            DataRow myrow;
            int icols = dt.Columns.Count;
            foreach (DataRow drow in dt.Rows)
            {
                myrow = dataGrideView1.NewRow();
                for (int i = 0; i <= icols - 1; i++)
                {

                    myrow[i] = drow.Cells[i].Value;
                }
                dt.Rows.Add(myrow);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to open my file using the following code:

```
private void openToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ds.ReadXml("items.xml");
        dataGridView1.Columns.Clear();
        dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];           
    }
```